# Synonyms created by deleted users cannot be approved or swapped

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process, moderator-tools

I cannot approve synonyms made by deleted users [on the synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Score&filter=Suggested). I'm met with a generic error popup instead. The request gives me nothing to go on either; it's just a 500 with no specific details.

I can still delete the pending synonyms, but I cannot swap the targets. I also can't swap targets on approved synonyms initially suggested by deleted users.

Approving, swapping, and deleting synonyms by non-deleted users still works fine, so it's only an issue when the user has since been deleted.

Comment: "An error occurred; please try again later"

Comment: @CodyGray Gotta love SE and their very specific error messages

Comment: I'm just pleased that they correctly used a semicolon.

Comment: One might even say the will of the dead is stronger than the will of moderators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixes for this are now live.

The tag synonym remains in the list, with the user "anon".

1. Can be **approved** as of Feb 7<sup>th</sup>, 2023.
2. Can be **swapped** as of Feb 9<sup>th</sup>, 2023.

Comment: Not sure if it's a result of this change, or if any other mods/staff are experiencing this... But now I'm getting the same error message mentioned above when I try to approve a tag synonym I suggested (e.g. on MSE).

Comment: @V2Blast Ah. Yup, looks like I've introduced a new bug with this fix. I've got a fix for that one in progress now

Comment: I'll leave it to you to update the status tag on this question to [status-completed] once you've got that final bug ironed out. :-) Thanks for working on it, and staying with it until the problem is fully resolved!

Comment: @V2Blast that should be fixed now. Third time lucky!

Comment: @Connell: Yep, seems to be working now. Thanks! :)